# Iphone drop down list

Tags: ios4

I didn't find the drop down list in iphone library.Instead of drop down list,is there any other alternative.please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use UIPickerView to select from a list of items.  If your list contains a large number of items, UITableView would probably be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using UIActionSheet for this.   If you keep adding many items to the actionsheet it turns into a uitable.  For me it's the ideal alternative.

[image]